Formalising proof of a rational number between any two reals number
I feel my question is a symptom of a larger issue I have with analysis, which is being unable to get the exact proof even when you have the right idea. It's also an issue of knowing how much rigour is necessary.
Here is my proof so far (with the right idea of taking the difference of the numbers and multiplying by a large enough integer so there is an integer between them):
suppose $ 0 < x < y, \ x, y\in \mathbb{R} $ (proof can be extended to negative reals easily)
there exists $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ s.t. $ N(y-x) > 1 \Leftrightarrow Ny - 1 > Nx $
$ Ny \geq \lfloor Ny \rfloor \geq Ny - 1 > Nx, \lfloor Ny \rfloor \in \mathbb{Z} $
$ x < \frac{\lfloor Ny \rfloor}{N} \leq y $
...and the issue here is the inequality is not strict. I know for a fact if the difference of two numbers is greater than 1, then there is an integer between them, but saying 'take m in Z between Nx and Ny' to me seems unrigorous. Maybe you should prove it? Maybe it is fine to say? This is the issue I have with analysis, I'm not sure of the amount of rigour necessary, especially important in an exam. But maybe in the same vein I should be questioning if we have to prove we can multiply the difference to get it larger than one (but I think that's fine). Let me know if it was a silly idea to use the floor function.

This really depends on your definitions, but the big important rule is the Archimedean property of the real numbers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property?wprov=sfti1

Questioning and feeling unsure is a perfectly natural place to be when learning proof-based mathematics—your experience is a common one! Good for you for leaning into the parts of math where you're not already strong. Observation: you never use the fact that $x>0$ in the proof, so this proof already extends to negative reals. Suggestion: if you instead use an $N$ such that $N(\frac y2-\frac x2)>1$, that might be a hack to get around the non-strict inequality issue.

I think that your underlying problem is that you are trying to re-invent the wheel.   In "Calculus" 2nd Ed., volume 1, Apostol spends about 20-30 pages developing Field Theory, slowly and carefully.  One of the end results is that Apostol proves that both the rational numbers and the irrational numbers are dense in $~\Bbb{R}.~$  I suggest finding a real analysis (AKA calculus) book that you are comfortable with, that  develops the theory.

There exist an $N$ so that $N(y-x) > 1$ can just as easily be stated as $N(y-x) > 2$ or $N(y-x) > 1.1$ or anything else. We could say: For all $\delta > 0$ there exist and $N$ so that $N(y-x)> 1+\delta$ so $Ny - (1+\delta) > Nx$ so $Ny > Ny-\delta \ge [Ny-\delta] > Nx$ and so $x < \frac {[Ny-\delta]}N < y$.

Alternatively.  The only time that you'd have $y = \frac {[Ny]}N$ would be if $Ny$ is an integer.  If so then $Ny -\frac 12\in \mathbb Q$ and $Nx < Ny-\frac 12 < Ny$ and $x < p=\frac{Ny-\frac 12}N < y$.

Hint. If you can find a rational between $0$ and $a/2$, then you can find one between $0$ and $a$. Can you extend this argument to finish your proof?
(By the way, you don't need $x>0$ at all for your argument as stated.)
Hope this helps. :)

for reals x<y, use my argument to find a rational between x and x + (y-x)/2, then this will be a rational strictly between x and y. Is that the argument you were looking for?

@thedanktouch: Precisely!

Use the Archemedian property of the real numbers:
Assume without loss of generality (wlog)
that $x>y$ then:
Set $\epsilon = x-y>0$
By Archemedian property there exists an $n\in N$ s.t.:
$\epsilon<\frac{1}{n}$
Then we have:
$x-y>\frac{1}{n}$
Thus:
$nx-ny>1$
Which implies there exists an integer $m$ s.t:
$nx<m<ny$
Implying:
$x<\frac{m}{n}<y$
Following correct comment by @Paul Sinclair:
Claim:
Let $x, y \in R$ assume
$(x-y>1)$
Then there exists an integer $m$ s.t.
$x<m<y$.
Proof:
Let $S=\{n \in Z|\; x<n\}$
Then since $S\subset Z$ and $S$ is bounded from below by $x$ it has a minimal element $m$
Then:
$m-1\notin S$
Implying
$m-1\leq x$
Thus:
$x<m\leq x+1<y$.
Which in conclusion shows that there exists an integer $m$ s.t $x<m<y$ when $x-y>1$.

"which implies there exists an integer $m$ s.t.". Why? (Yes, it is true, but it also must be proven rigorously.)

Thank you Paul i have added a rigorous proof for such an existence.
